# Newbie confounded by mod_wsgi/apache/django settings

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

this is my first post on SO. I've become too frustrated to continue researching this, so I'm just going to post my settings and see if someone is willing to help.

When I run Apache as a service (as an administrator), first off, the document root allows me to access my files through url (not cool, but not really my issue because I know it's the document root setting in the Apache conf). Secondly, when I type in 127.0.0.1/blog/blog/ it throws a 500 error and the Apache log reads:

```
[Tue Sep 24 19:44:20 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=2152): Create interpreter '127.0.0.1|/blog'.
[Tue Sep 24 19:44:20 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=2152): Adding 'C:/Users/jdp/Documents/www/mysite.com' to path.
[Tue Sep 24 19:44:20 2013] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2152, process='', application='127.0.0.1|/blog'): Loading WSGI script 'C:/Users/jdp/Documents/www/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Sep 24 19:49:40 2013] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 10053)An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Tue Sep 24 19:49:40 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2152): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Users/jdp/Documents/www/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Sep 24 19:49:40 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Tue Sep 24 19:49:48 2013] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 10053)An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Tue Sep 24 19:49:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2152): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Users/jdp/Documents/www/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Sep 24 19:49:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Tue Sep 24 19:52:10 2013] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 10053)An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Tue Sep 24 19:52:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2152): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Users/jdp/Documents/www/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Sep 24 19:52:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
```

On windows, by the way.

first up: http.conf:

```
WSGIPythonPath C:/Users/jdp/Documents/www/mysite.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias randomserver.com
    ServerAdmin randomguy@example.com

    DocumentRoot C:/Users/usr/Documents/www/

    <Directory C:/Users/usr/Documents/www/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    WSGIScriptAlias /blog C:/Users/usr/Documents/www/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py


    <Directory C:/Users/usr/Documents/www/mysite.com/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny, allow
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

originally I was attempting to do:

```
WSGIPythonPath C:/Users/usr/Documents/www/mysite.com:C:/Users/jdp/Documents/site/env/Lib/site-packages
```

but that caused problems with the path #1 and I couldn't import mysite.settings.
I left it out and just downloaded the missing packages to my root python directory.

Here are my settings in C:/Users/usr/Documents/www/mysite.com/mysite/settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_db',                      
        'USER': 'usr',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      
        'PORT': '0080',                      
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


TIME_ZONE = 'America\New_York'


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True


USE_TZ = True


MEDIA_ROOT = r'C:\Users\usr\Documents\site\mysite\media'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = '*********************************'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/usr/Documents/www/mysite.com/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'blog',
    'south',
    'django.contrib.markup',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
```

}

Aaaaaaand here's my wsgi.py file:

```
import os

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blogs')),
)
```

Not sure if any other information would be useful. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've spent too many hours trying little tweaks and searching SO and the mod_wsgi documentation to little avail. Maybe I'm biting off more than I can chew since I'm new to programming, but I don't think I've been stuck like this yet.

Comment: Just to check, can you do python manage.py runserver successfully?  (and then connect to localhost:8000)

Comment: Also, I don't think this is your problem, but your postgres port in settings.py probably shouldn't be 0080; generally it's 4321 IIRC.

Comment: Related to this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204594? Maybe try Apache on a high numbered port like 8080.

Comment: HA! You got me started down the right track! When I ran the development server with debug=True, it gave me an unknown timezone error because I had America\New_York. Changed it to America/New_York and fired up apache and it loads! Thank you!

Comment: Well, I guess I jumped the gun there because with debug=False it didn't work. I'll come back to this tomorrow. Still gives a 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put your project source code under DocumentRoot, that is documented in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Mounting_The_WSGI_Application

That will ensure your source code is not accessible.

The 500 error was because of your broken code and because you perhaps hadn't otherwise correctly setup Django to log details of the error in some other way. You appear to be trying to have it email you the errors using the logging system, but those messages may not be getting through because you haven't set ADMINS.

Enabling DEBUG mode allowed the error to be shown in the browser instead.

FWIW, the error:

```
IOError: failed to write data
```

is because the connection from your browser was killed before any response could be written back. You may have forced a page reload or something.

Comment: Looks like I misread your documentation when I was setting up my virtual host, that's why I had my document root set to that directory. What exactly do I want to keep in the document root? Won't the website load as long as the WSGIAlias is set up properly?

Comment: But your site is at a sub URL, so anything outside of that sub URL is still mapped to DocumentRoot for static files etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Foon @Graham Dumpleton

Thanks! Once I changed my database settings to match my postgres settings in PGAdmin and fixed the timezone bug, my page loads.

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
     ('usr', 'usr@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'django_db',    
        'USER': 'usr',
        'PASSWORD': 'blahblahblah',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                    
        'PORT': '5432',                     
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
```

Now I just need to figure out how to configure my static files on a server.